# Python: Inheritance and default values in __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, default, init

I am trying to make a class with generic `__init__` values, but have defaults for its subclasses, as so:

```
class Enemy:

 def __init__(self, difficulty, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name):
    self.power = power + 2*difficulty
    self.HP = self.MaxHP = MaxHP + 5*difficulty
    self.magic = magic + 2* difficulty
    self.MP = self.MaxMP = MaxMP + 5*difficulty
class Goblin(Enemy):
 def __init_(self, difficulty = 1, power = 1, MaxHP = 5, magic = 1, MaxMP = 5, speed = 5, name = "Goblin"):
    super(Goblin, self).__init__(self, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name)
```

However, when I try to make a Goblin object without the full number of default values (like, I'll just put in a value for difficulty), it tells me I need the full 8 arguments even though the rest are given default values.  Is there any reason I can't do that or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're missing an underscore from Goblin's `__init__`. So you should copy and paste the code that is causing the problem. And the full traceback, too. Python's tracebacks are usually very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you called `super(Goblin, self).__init__(self, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name)` without `difficulty`.  You probably also want to inherit like `class Enemy(object)` to make sure `Enemy` is a new-style class if you're on 2.x (which I guess you must be, considering the old way that you've used `super`).

Here's a simpler example:

```
class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self, talk):
    print '__init__ Animal: ', talk

class Cat(Animal):
  def __init__(self, talk='meow'):
    print '__init__ Cat'
    super(Cat, self).__init__(talk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tom = Cat()
```

Outputs :

```
__init__ Cat
__init__ Animal:  meow
```

---

*Edit:*

Well if the following doesn't work, perhaps you have old class definitions cached in your interpreter (try running it on a fresh interpreter).

```
class Enemy(object):
  def __init__(self, difficulty, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name):
    self.power = power + 2*difficulty
    self.HP = self.MaxHP = MaxHP + 5*difficulty
    self.magic = magic + 2* difficulty
    self.MP = self.MaxMP = MaxMP + 5*difficulty
    print 'Raaarghh!! I am the formidable {}.'.format(name)

class Goblin(Enemy):
  def __init__(self, difficulty=1, power=1, MaxHP=5, magic=1, MaxMP=5, speed=5, name="Goblin"):
    super(Goblin, self).__init__(difficulty, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  g = Goblin(name='user1038783 goblin')
```

Comment: Hah, the things you miss when you think you tried everything.  And thank you for the Object part.

Comment: I tried running the program again (as opposed to my test driver), and even with difficulty there I still get the same error "TypeError: __init__ takes exactly 8 arguments, 2 given"

Comment: OK, check the double underscore in the `__init__` , and don't pass in `self` explicitly because it gets done implicitly.

Comment: The __init__() was spelled correctly, and I tried all combos of removing the self from (Goblin, self) and (self, difficulty, power...), and I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, difficulty, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name):
        self.power = power + 2*difficulty
        self.HP = self.MaxHP = MaxHP + 5*difficulty
        self.magic = magic + 2* difficulty
        self.MP = self.MaxMP = MaxMP + 5*difficulty

class Goblin(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, difficulty = 1, power = 1, MaxHP = 5, magic = 1, MaxMP = 5, speed = 5, name = "Goblin"):
        super(Goblin, self).__init__(difficulty, power, MaxHP, magic, MaxMP, speed, name)
```

The ways I had to change yours to get it to work:

1. Fix misspelled `def __init__` in `Goblin`.

   - Symptom: `Goblin()` raised `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 8 arguments (1 given)`, as Goblin had not defined an `__init__` method, so it had inherited the one without defaults from `Enemy`
2. Change `Enemy` into a new-style class by inheriting from `object`

   - Symptom: I got `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` on the call to `super()`; I'm not sure whether older versions of Python would have allowed it or triggered a different error, but I know old-style classes have different MRO (method resolution order) rules than new-style classes, and I believe this could make `super` screwy anyway.
3. Remove the second `self` from the call to `super(Goblin, self).__init__(self, ...)`

   - Symptom: `self` is automatically passed to `super(Class, self).some_method(...)`, so putting it in there yourself is like calling `Enemy.__init__(self, self, difficulty, power, ...)`.
4. Added `difficulty` to the call to `super(Goblin, self).__init__(...)`

   - Symptom: You were getting difficulty defaulted in `Goblin.__init__`, but then not passing the value up to `Enemy.__init__`.

I think that was about it.

Comment: Ah yes, wim mentioned the __init__ being mistyped but I missed that again when I checked it over.  Thanks to both of you, it's working now.